# Plex client can't find server, goes to relay mode

Tags: plex

I have just installed Plex Media on my laptop with Ubuntu 16.04.  No other devices on my network can see it.  Both my Rokus and my windows 10 PC go to Relay Mode.  In this mode, playback is so slow as to be unusable.  I have turned off the VPN on laptop.  Made no difference.

I had set up the same software on my very old laptop (with VPN) with out this issue.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Firewalling might be a cause for this problem. Did you set up ufw or other iptables frontends?

Comment: @Phillip-ZyanKLee-Stockmann:  I don't think any special firewall settings are needed for devices on the network to see this server.  I never needed to do anything using the stock installation.

Comment: @MartyFried on the contrary: special firewall settings might disable access to the plex server. So if there is a firewalling solution in place on this laptop, OP would be required to allow access to plesk or disable the firewalling completely (not advisable though, as there probably was a reason for a firewall).